# jQuery Problem - How to solve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery requirement like:

I have an Image. If I click it once its size will get reduced. If I again click it it will again resize.

Do we have any functionality to do it easily in jQuery? Or do I have to set a flag and then work on mouseclick? Something like

```
  $("#img1").click(function() {
      $("#img1").addClass("img1");
  });
```

Comment: Why downvote when somebody already provided the perfect solution which  I have accepted? will b greatful if the downvoter mention the reason.

Comment: Maybe because solution for problem seems too obvious. Anyway: 1 upvote == 10 downvotes. And answers are what matters here not that reputation thingy. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use toggle, when there is toggleClass function :)

```
$("#img1").click(function() {
  $("#img1").toggleClass("img1");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery [toggle function](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/) might help.

In short=>

CSS:

```
.small{width: 10px;}
```

Javascript:

```
var makeSmall = function(){
            $(this).addClass("small");
        };

var makeNormal = function () {
        $(this).removeClass("small");
    };

$("#id").toggle(makeSmall, makeNormal);
```

Also - you might want to change CSS directly through jQuery:

```
var makeSmall = function(){
    $(this).css({'width' : '10px'});
}
```

P.s. Thinker's approach with toggleClass is cleaner.

Comment: Thnaks Arnis, u explained Toggle in a real simple manner.I got the point.